# « [...] qui m’a (mis au fait/notifié/informé de) quelque chose » : quelle formulation est la plus usuelle ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> C’est Johanne, esthéticienne, à l’occasion d’une consultation en clinique, qui m’a **mis au fait de** [l’existence de] ce soin esthétique que je ne connaissais point et qui apparemment constitue une nouvelle mode chez les jeunes.

> C’est Johanne, esthéticienne, à l’occasion d’une consultation en clinique, qui m’a **notifié** l’existence de ce nouveau soin esthétique que je ne connaissais point et qui apparemment constitue une nouvelle mode chez les jeunes.

> C’est Johanne, esthéticienne, à l’occasion d’une consultation en clinique, qui m’a **informé de** [l’existence de] ce nouveau soin esthétique que je ne connaissais point et qui apparemment constitue une nouvelle mode chez les jeunes.

———————————————————————

Vous pouvez aussi me proposer une autre énonciation, en mettant l’accent sur le premier segment de la phrase qui renferme le verbe devant lequel j’hésite.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que l'on notifie quelqu'un quand on se trouve en leur présence. A mon avis, cela se ferait à distance. Aussi, un autre avis: ne....point est très formel en français. Parler d'une esthéticienne et utiliser la négation ne...point dans la même phrase fait un peu "précieux".  Elle m'a fait connaître ce soin etc.

Comment: Je suis entièrement d’accord avec vous, merci Lambie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On notifie quelqu'un d'une notification:

> Il m'a notifié que le dîner était prêt

On informe quelqu'un d'une information, comme dans votre cas:

> elle m’a informé de [l’existence de] ce nouveau soin.

On peut aussi dire:

> elle m’a parlé de ce nouveau soin.

Answer (score 0):

En [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50267/quelle-serait-la-fa%C3%A7on-la-plus-usuelle-d-exprimer-l-id%C3%A9e-plus-bas#comment104236_50267) (Lambie), on trouve (légèrement modifié):

> Je ne pense pas que l'on notifie quelqu'un quand on se trouve en [sa]
> présence. À mon avis, cela se ferait à distance. Aussi, un autre avis:
> *ne... point* est très formel en français. Parler d'une esthéticienne et utiliser la négation *ne... point* dans la même phrase fait un peu
> « précieux ». *[Elle] m'a fait connaître ce soin etc.*